# Installing Windows from a partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-installation

Ok so I have left my USB pen in work and I want to install the Windows 8 Consumer Preview onto my netbook.

Can I setup a partition on my netbook, put the Windows installer files onto that and boot from it?

I have used the computer manager snap in to create an 8GB NTFS partition on my hard drive. I have then download the Windows 8 ISO. I guess I now need to do three things.

1. Add an entry in the Windows 7 boot loader pointed to my new partition
2. Extract the contents of the ISO onto the partition
3. Change the properties of the partition in some way to make it bootable

Two questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. How do I go about achieving the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Extract your ISO file to the 8Gb partition's root folder.
2. Use Disk Manager to mark that partiton as active.
3. Open cmd and type the following command, not include the double quote, asuming E is your 8GB partition

`E:`

`cd boot`

`bootsect /nt60 E: /force /mbr`

Now you can boot into your windows 8 installation. To boot it back to your windows you can use the repair tool inside the windows installation.

Comment: PS: for a partition to be marked as active, it needs to be primary.