# Can I do a clean installation of Windows 8 without burning any DVD?

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

Now I have the ISO file but I don't want to burn it into DVD so I wonder if there is a way to install Windows 8 right from hard disk ? (do a clean installation from DOS not from any Windows system)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two main solutions to install Windows 8 without any optical media (typically using a 4Gb+ USB flash drive).

**1. The "Upgrade Assistant" official (promoted) one**

If you are already using a previous version of Windows, you can launch the [Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-hk/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) which, among other things, "provides the option to buy, download, and install Windows 8".  You can download the ISO file or create a bootable flash drive from this wizard.  **If you need the ISO file** or if you prefer to use this official solution, I recommend the excellent [How To Clean Install Windows 8 Pro Upgrade](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/clean-install-windows-8-upgrade.htm) step-by-step tutorial.

By the way, since I bought Windows 8 online, I didn't receive any DVD or even any link to download an ISO, so this first solution is the only one I came up with to download the file and proceed to the installation...

**2. The "Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool" official-but-not-really-promoted one**

This solution requires you to own the ISO file already (cf. solution #1).  Actually [The Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) won't download anything, but it will help you to get your flash drive ready for the installation.

> This free program from Microsoft properly formats your flash drive and then copies the contents of the Windows 8 installation ISO file you have to that flash drive.

Once again, there are some nice and clear step-by-step tutorials over the Web, like [How To Install Windows 8 From a USB Device](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/install-windows-8-usb.htm).

Also you might want to know about [an interesting third alternative found on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/428484/installing-windows-from-a-partition) that will spare you a DVD *and* a flash drive:

**3. Install from a partition**

Start by creating a 8GB NTFS partition on your hard drive.  Then

> 1. Extract your ISO file to the 8Gb partition's root folder.
> 2. Use Disk Manager to mark that partiton as active.
> 3. Open cmd and type the following command, not include the double quote, asuming E is your 8GB partition
>
> `E:`
>        `cd boot`
>        `bootsect /nt60 E: /force /mbr`
>
> Now you can boot into your windows 8 installation. To boot it back to
>   your windows you can use the repair tool inside the windows
>   installation.

Answer (score 2):

Bootable USB memory stick (plenty of detailed instructions online as to how to create it) is the only non-DVD local option. I don't believe it's possible to install it from an ISO just on a partition on the local hard drive.

It is possible to install from a Network Share but this of course involves a second machine and is more complicated.

Comment: The simplest way to create the bootable USB flash drive is to use Windows 7 (yes it works for Win8 ISO as well) USB/DVD Download Tool   http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool